# How do i install Windows on SSD?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, drivers, ssd, sata

I've purchased this SSD: **CRUCIAL M4 CT256M4SSD2**, 256GB, SATA III.

And i have a following MB: [**ASUS P8P67 EVO REV 3.0**](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P8P67_EVO/)

MB and SSD are updated to the latest version of BIOS and firmware.

When i start to install Windows 8 or Windows 7, the installer tells me that it can't find a driver for the disk drive and there is no drives in the list, so i can't select anything.

How do i install Windows 8 or 7 to the SSD?

P/S:

- I've connected SSD to the SATA3 6Gb port on the MB.
- SSD is the only disk drive in the system (apart from USB FLASH from which i'm starting Windows installation).
- SSD is detected by the BIOS, i can see it in the POST report, i can even work with it using GParted Live USB.
- I've tried both Intel P67 6Gb ports and Marvell ones.
- Feeding the proper drivers to the Windows installer is not helping.
- And the most awesome part is that installer allows me to load drivers from the SSD partition!
- I've tried installing Windows from USB flash drive created with Rufus 1.3.4 or DISKPART-BOOTSECT method.

Comment: Do you have any other drives plugged in? If you do, try with just the SSD plugged in.

Comment: You should be able to see the drive in your BIOS first of all, then you should be able to narrow down your issue from there.

Comment: You install Windows on a ssd just like you would on a hdd.

Comment: Check the manufacturer's website for drivers, and download them - unzip them or whatever to a USB key. Windows Setup will prompt you (as you've seen) to provide them. This happens because either your motherboard, the SSD, or both are enough newer than Windows 7/Windows 8 that they don't come with the built-in ability to detect the drives. It's always been like this.

Comment: and by "always been like this" I mean we used to have to hit F8 and insert a floppy disk with drivers for our SCSI hard drives.

Comment: @MarkAllen Why don't you convert those two comments to an answer? They're exactly what the asker needs to know, and should be eligible for reputation on that basis.

Comment: There are no drivers on the Crucial website. The only downloadable thing for this drive is firmware update. And there were no disks inside the package.

Comment: Here's the support page for Crucial M4 drive: http://www.crucial.com/support/firmware.aspx

Comment: Here's the ASUS support page - you might only need to download drivers for the controller built-in to your motherboard: http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P8P67_EVO/#support_Download_36

Comment: and similar: http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/305459-30-asus-p8p67-hard-disk-detected

Comment: In the BIOS, is it AHCI, or IDE mode? IDE mode should have no issue. AHCI mode... you may need driver (from the motherboard manufacturer)

Comment: Controller is in the RAID mode. I'm using RAID for two of my other disks (temporarily disconnected). But neither AHCI, nor IDE modes helped.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the data cable to the sata 2 slot. Some motherboards treat the 6g differently. After installing Windows and the chipset drivers, switch it back

Comment: I've tried all ports and all controller modes.